# Argument not reflected in Python function call

Tags: python, django

I'm calling a class method like this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(self.req_proxy.generate_proxied_request(some_url).text, "html.parser", "United States")
```

and the class method is defined like this:

```
def generate_proxied_request(self, url, params={}, req_timeout=30, country=None):
    if country is not None:
        searched_proxies = []
        for proxy in self.proxy_list:
            if str(proxy[1]) == country:
                searched_proxies.append(proxy)
    else:
        searched_proxies = self.proxy_list
```

`United States` is meant to resolve to the `country` variable, but it doesn't. When the function is called, it takes the value `None`. Why isn't `country` reflecting the `United States` value?

Comment: you put `Unitet State` in wrong place - now it is parameter for `BeautifulSoup`., You have to put it `(some_url, country='United State')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `"United States"` to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor and not to the `generate_proxied_request` method where it is supposed to go.

The following would be correct:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(self.req_proxy.generate_proxied_request(some_url, country="United States").text, "html.parser")
```

The `BeautifulSoup` constructor [is defined](https://github.com/newvem/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/__init__.py#L68) like:

```
def __init__(self, markup="", features=None, builder=None,
             parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, **kwargs):
    ...
```

so in the current form you are assigning `"United States"` to the `builder` argument.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(self.req_proxy.generate_proxied_request(some_url, country="United States").text, "html.parser")`
```